# Why does Java-regex matches underscore?

Tags: java, regex, url

I was trying to match the URL pattern `string.string.` for any number of `string.` using `^([^\\W_]+.)([^\\W_]+.)$` as a first attempt, and it works for matching two consecutive patterns. But then, when I generalize it to `^([^\\W_]+.)+$` stops working and matches the wrong pattern "string.str_ing.".
Do you know what is incorrect with the second version?

Comment: Please escape the `.` since it is a metacharacter.

Comment: `\w` entails the underscore too. Also since a couple of years URLs may contain Unicode letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape your . character, else it will match any character including _.

```
^([^\\W_]+\.?)+$
```

this can be your generalised regex

Answer (score 0):

With `^([^\\W_]+.)([^\\W_]+.)$` you match any two words with restricted set of characters. Although, you have not escaped the `.`, it still works as long as the first word is matched first `string`, then any literal (that's what unescaped `.` means) and then `string` again.

In the latter one the unescaped dot (`.`) is a part of the capturing group occurring at least once (since you use `+`), therefore it allows any character as a **divisor**. In other words `string.str_ing.` is understood as:

- `string` as the 1st word
- `str` as the 2nd word
- `ing` as the 3rd word

... as long as the unescaped dot (`.`) allows any divisor (both `.` literally and `_`).

Escape the dot to make the Regex work as intented ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/TSaQsb/1)):

```
^([^\\W_]+\.)+$
```

Answer (score 0):

[^\W] seems a weird choice - it's matching 'not not-a-word-character'.  I haven't thought it through, but that sounds like it's equivalent to \w, i.e., matching a word character.

Either way, with ^\W and \w, you're asking to match underscores - which is why it matches the string with the underscore.  "Word characters" are uppercase alphabetics, lowercase alphabetics, digits, **and underscore**.

You probably want [a-z]+  or maybe [A-Za-z0-9]+

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. The content of the `[]` says that anything except `/` literally (`//`). The `\W` (it should be `\w` anyway) doesn't work as a shortcut for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` since the initial two backslashes (`\\`) have own meaning and the `W`/`w` character remains unescaped. The three ones should be included to take an effect (and a lower-case `w`).

Comment: There are no slashes, only backslashes, in the given regex. I assumed the \\ is just Java source syntax for a single \. Otherwise the expression is just bizarre - [^\\W_]+ matches a string of characters except for backslash, W, and underscore.   Which might well have given the result seen, but it doesn't seem like a useful parsing, and I doubt it was intended.